# Why local Stockfish Eval is not matching with Chess.com and Lichess.org?

Tags: stockfish, lichess, chess.com

Experimenting with stockfish and stuck on a situation.
PGN (The Game of the Century)

`1. Nf3 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. d4 O-O 5. Bf4 d5 6. Qb3 dxc4 7. Qxc4 c6 8. e4 Nbd7 9. Rd1 Nb6 10. Qc5 Bg4 11. Bg5 Na4 12. Qa3 Nxc3 13. bxc3 Nxe4 14. Bxe7 Qb6 15. Bc4 Nxc3 16. Bc5 Rfe8+ 17. Kf1 Be6 18. Bxb6 Bxc4+ 19. Kg1 Ne2+ 20. Kf1 Nxd4+ 21. Kg1 Ne2+ 22. Kf1 Nc3+ 23. Kg1 axb6 24. Qb4 Ra4 25. Qxb6 Nxd1 26. h3 Rxa2 27. Kh2 Nxf2 28. Re1 Rxe1 29. Qd8+ Bf8 30. Nxe1 Bd5 31. Nf3 Ne4 32. Qb8 b5 33. h4 h5 34. Ne5 Kg7 35. Kg1 Bc5+ 36. Kf1 Ng3+ 37. Ke1 Bb4+ 38. Kd1 Bb3+ 39. Kc1 Ne2+ 40. Kb1 Nc3+ 41. Kc1 Rc2# 0-1`

Now after `18. Bxb6` (FEN `r3r1k1/pp3pbp/1Bp1b1p1/8/2BP4/Q1n2N2/P4PPP/3R1K1R b - - 0 18`) both the Chess.com (-5.47) and Lichess.org (-8.3) showing `Black` is good position but when I test this on my local stockfish 16, it's showing white is in Good Position (+6.06). [image]

Any suggestion what I'm missing?

This is how I'm testing-

`position fen r3r1k1/pp3pbp/1Bp1b1p1/8/2BP4/Q1n2N2/P4PPP/3R1K1R b - - 0 18`

`eval`

Comment: I just pasted this to lichess to analyze it with SF14 and analyzed it with my local SF16. I cannot reproduce your issue. Both, my local SF16 and SF running in the Browser evaluate the position as lost for White with Bxc4 as an only move, every other move losing. My guess is that you're confusing something, using SF from the terminal.

Comment: Stockfish is still confusing to me. 
What I did so far-
`position fen r3r1k1/pp3pbp/1Bp1b1p1/8/2BP4/Q1n2N2/P4PPP/3R1K1R b - - 0 18`
`eval`
@Hauptideal

Comment: Tried both on Windows SF 16 and Ubuntu SF 16. Same Eval +6.
So, I'm for sure I'm confusing something.
@Hauptideal

Comment: Have you found this problem just for this very specific position after move 18 of the Game of the Century, or does it apply more generally? Maybe it's just reporting the value of the position from the perspective of the player to move. What do you see reported for the position with FEN rnbqkbnr/pppppp1p/6p1/7Q/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNB1KBNR b KQkq - 1 2 ?

Answer (score 5):

The `eval` command returns a static evaluation, so just the position without any search. Therefore, the local command and the online tools return different results.

Comment: Exactly. It could be added that in order to ask SF to analyze a position from the command line, the proper command isn't "eval" but "go".
Ok, another interesting point: it seems the "go" command gives the evaluation from the point of view of the side to play. So in this position, "go" gives a plus score since black is winning and it's black's turn.

Answer (score 1):

The online tools have a specific depth, ponder, CPU and other such parameter values, out of which some can be editted in lichess.org. Chess.com on the other hand, uses other engines, by which I mean not Stockfish 15+, and therefore presents different results. If you actually view it, you realise that it is either Komodo, or the latest version of stockfish available is stockfish 11. Parameters such as depth are probably different in both cases as well.'

Now, when you open it locally, the same parameters are not 'tuned' as per lichess.org, and the depth is usually 24 or so, in contrast to lichess.org which is now updated to be infinite!